# How do I use a JS variable in document.getElementById().style?

Tags: javascript, css

I want to make it so when ever I reload the page, the background gets chosen randomly.

```
function switchBG(urlThing) {
        document.getElementById("bg-img").style.display="block";
        document.getElementById("bg-img").style.backgroundImage="url(urlThing)";
    }

    var n = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 1);

    if (n == 1) {
        switchBG('back1.jpg');
    }
    else if (n == 2) {
        switchBG('back2.jpg')
    }
```

I tried that, but nothing happened.

Edit: This is the div. It's the first thing under the  tag.

```
<div id="bg-img"></div>
```

Comment: You need to concatenate the `urlThing` variable with the `backgroundImage` style text. As is, you're just putting it as a literal string, which won't work.

Comment: @CertainPerformance mens this: `"url(" + urlThing + ")"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming bg-img is the `<img>` tag.
this is how you can do it

```
function switchBG(urlThing) {
    document.getElementById("bg-img").style.display="block";
    var loc = window.location.pathname;
    var dir = loc.substring(0, loc.lastIndexOf('/'));
    document.getElementById("bg-img").src=dir + urlThing;
}
```

Comment: bg-img is a <div>

Comment: Ok then,for div you can use
`document.getElementById("bg-img").style.backgroundImage="url(" + urlThing + ")"; `
also press f12 and check in styles if your image is loaded. if it is then you need to add css to that div to display image

try 
`<style type="text/css">
    div {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>`

Comment: That worked, but how do I make the div fill the body?

Comment: try changing css, I gave that css just to make img visible.

Comment: if you want the div to fill the body try `<style type="text/css"> #bg-img { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; } </style>`

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate the variable like this:

```
document.getElementById("bg-img").style.backgroundImage="url(" + urlThing + ")";
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work

Comment: You also need to choose a width and a height. Otherwise the div is empty.